# What was the best tank of WW2 ?

Tags: world-war-two, war, tanks

I believe it's the T-34, but a friend of mine argued that it was the Tiger. It all depends on which period of WW2 you look at, but overall, which was the best ?

Comment: They were all suited to particular needs. There is no answer.

Comment: The T-34 was the Tiger of its time - overpowered and few in number. By the time the Tiger appeared, the T-34 was mid-range but produced in absurd quantity.

Comment: The Tiger Tank while terribly underpowered was and in many ways still is the greatest Tank ever made. The T-34 was functionally the best Tank of World War 2...diesel powered ironically...medium Tank though so lacking in firepower and range. The best Tank engineering wise by far was the American Hellcat...by far the best Tank ever made actually as Tanks are weapons of manover

Comment: What makes the Tiger the best tank ever made ?

Comment: VtC as opinion based.

Comment: The firepower, range of the round, accuracy of the round, defensive armor, etc truly made it the King of Tanks in WW2. Gasoline powered engine was really weak so unlike the T-34 it was no good in an attacking role. Plus the Tiger was heavily used so we can measure it's performance. That's not as true as the Hellcat which is I think the greatest tank ever made because it used an air-cooled radial engine, was very light, great firepower and even by today's standards awesome spp

Comment: WWII lasted from 1939 to 1945, and at various times there were different "best tanks", whatever criterion you use to define "the best".

Comment: On a one-on-one fight the Tiger would beat the T-34 most of the time.  But it was usually 4 or more T-34s vs each Tiger.  As Stalin said "quantity has a quality all of its own".

Comment: Maybe rephrase to "most effective tank" or "which tank was most revolutionary"?

Comment: @DJSims Do you have any cite for that? Germany was short of just about everything, including metals, especially around the time of the Tiger. USSR had way more metals than Germany, even before you factor in Lend-Lease, unless I am wildly mis-remembering something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## There is no best tank

There was no *best* tank simply because there is no objective measure.

The Russian T-34 and the German Panther tank have been described as outstanding and trend-setting for future tank designs.

At certain times in the war, certain tank models were nearly invincible in direct combat. Examples would include British Matilda tanks in the Battle of France and German Tigers early in the Russian campaign.

Some tanks were not exactly great in combat, but could be mass-produced easily so they had the advantage in numbers. American Shermans would be a prime example. But again, there is no measure of *best*. As a country, mass producing cheap tanks is great. As a person sitting in such a tank, I would have liked another tank better.

Please also note that tank warfare in WW2 has never been decided by the quality of the tank, but by combined arms, maneuver, tactics and quality of the crew and leadership. For example early in the war, a tank squad where each tank had a radio was *way* more effective than a group of supposedly "better" tanks that was unable to properly communicate.

Comment: Just a note. The first tigers appeared in late 1942 so it was after the "Barbarossa" campaign.

Comment: @wawa I don't know if Barbarossa officially ended at some point. People use it to describe the complete German campaign in the east. I renamed it Russian campaign because you are right, there were no Tigers in what was *planned* as Barbarossa.

Comment: oh, I see. Barbarossa was from the initial German attack until the failure of capturing Moscow (Dec. 1941). You can do it with some more detail and saying it ended in Sept. 1941 and was relieved by operation "Typhoon". In 1942 it was operation "Fall Blau" (Stalingrad and caucasian campaign of Army Group South). In 1943 it was operation "Zitadelle" (Battle of Kursk) and after that I guess there wasn't any major German offensives in the East. :)